# Embed video (not youtube or vimeo) to online survey with hidden controls

Tags: video, embed

I would like to embed videos to an online survey without the user to be able to see the time display, but to be able to play and stop. I know how to do this with YouTube, but for copyright issues, this is not an option and it seems that on a basic vimeo account, one cannot hide the time display. How else could I possibly achieve a video with no time display embedded?

So, the mp4 video that I would like to embed is this: drive.google.com/file/d/0B66ZiZzQ_tMLcW94X2JrVXZWUXc/view

And the code that I'm trying to embed it with just to get it to play is this:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="drive.google.com/file/d/0B66ZiZzQ_tMLcW94X2JrVXZWUXc/view" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

But I'm not getting successful results. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is for an online experiment involving watching short videos and answering questions. I would like the subject not to see the time display because some of the questions concern a subjective perception of time and I would like them not to know how long the clip is.

Answer (score 0):

The [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) element supports `controls`.

> If this attribute is present, the browser will offer controls to allow the user to control video playback, including volume, seeking, and pause/resume playback.

But if you set `controls` for a HTML5 video, *all* controls *the browser* supports are displayed. So the modern approach to video using HTML5 will not work for you.

You will have to look for a custom player. I know none.

Comment: So you don't think it's possible? I am trying to do it using the HTML5 video tag. I'm really not well versed in this and am sure that I'm doing something wrong.

So, the mp4 video that I would like to embed is this:

drive.google.com/file/d/0B66ZiZzQ_tMLcW94X2JrVXZWUXc/view

And the code that I'm trying to embed it with just to get it to play is this:

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="drive.google.com/file/d/0B66ZiZzQ_tMLcW94X2JrVXZWUXc/view" type="video/mp4">
</video>

But I'm not getting successful results. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and put the HTML there. Don't put code into a comment.